# Ubuntu upgrade to 20.04 on AMD Black screen, blinking cursor

Tags: upgrade, updates, ubuntu-20.04, amd-graphics-card, bug

This seems to be a common problem but I can't find a solution. As mentioned in the title after upgrade, Ubuntu boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor.

The boot sequence is as follow:

- Bios splash screen
- Grub screen
- Ubuntu splash screen with the loading circle
- Black screen with blinking cursor

The system is active. I can access the command line, issue commands, update and reboot the system.
So I suppose that something with the graphics part of the system fails. I do not know where to look for error messages.

I tried purging and reinstalling gdm3, setting up a ppa to access updated amd drivers but nothing changed.

How to find out what is the error and how to fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

After spending the day on it, it turns out that the problem was coming from a previous manual installation of the graphic card driver. Removing it solved everything:

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the command line you can check `/var/log/syslog` with nano, vi or mc. Or run `journalctl -b -0` to examine the current boot log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I can indeed access the logs but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. Each seems to have thousands of pages.